# how to select this entity in repository

Tags: typescript, orm, nestjs, typeorm, bcrypt

How can I select `this` entity in when creating a repository method in typeorm?

I am trying to select password property on Admin entity but `this` selects Repository not entity

```
@EntityRepository(Admin)
export class AdminRepository extends Repository<Admin> {

  async comparePasswords(password: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return await compare(password, this.password);
  }

}
```

Comment: this class deals with repository instances, not entities. Why not just pass them as parameter? Or just move this method to `Admin` class (but I'm pretty sure that could be seen as a bad practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a custom repository like this:

`admin.repository.ts`

```
@EntityRepository(Admin)
export class AdminRepository extends Repository<Admin> {}
```

You can use it, for example, in a service or controller (or other class) by injecting it on the constructor like this:

`admin.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(AdminRepository)
        private adminRepository: AdminRepository,
    ) {}

    async findAdminByName(name: string): Promise<boolean> {
      return await = this.adminRepository.findOne({name});
    }
}
```

But if you don't actually need to implement custom methods on repository class ([take a look to all standard TypeOrm repository methods](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_repository_repository_.repository.html)), you can achieve the same result without creating the custom repository file `admin.repository.ts`, and injecting it on the fly directly on a service:

`admin.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Admin)
        private adminRepository: Repository<Admin>,
    ) {}

    async findAdminByName(name: string): Promise<boolean> {
      return await = this.adminRepository.findOne({name});
    }
}
```

Take a look also to the doc [Repository Pattern](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Method moved to Entity class .